# After disabling packrat can I remove packrat folder from the directory?

Tags: directory, packrat

Since I am using a cloud folder with limited space availability for my R project, I decided to disable packrat for my project and use the local library instead.
It worked, but the packrat folder inside my project folder is still there, taking quite some space. Can I just delete it?
thanks
Giulia

Answer (score 0):

I'm lacking official confirmation, but I'm going to say yes you can safely delete the packrat directories and files after disabling it. I've tried it and see no downsides yet. If you don't disable it first there will likely need to be some additional cleanup to do. If you need packrat again you should be able to start over the same as usual.